# Why there is a need of using tf.Variable?

Tags: tensorflow

In the following code I am unable to understand the need of using tf.Variable? I get the same value whether I use tf.Variable or omit it.

```
`initial = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal(shape=[1,10,1], mean=0, 
stddev=0.1,seed=123))`
```

Comment: Documentation says that it maintains the state of the graph. What does it mean? If I don't implement tf.Variable in the above code what will be its effect?

Answer (score 0):

As I answered in your another post, I will post it again, In `tensorflow`, anything that is created using `tf.Variable()`, will get updated during training in back-propagation, for example, a weight matrix.

Ideally, by default, every `tf.Variable()` becomes trainable unless you specify it `non-trainable` explicitly.

If you do this `initial = tf.truncated_normal([5,10], mean=0, stddev=0.1)`, then tensorflow will not know that it's a trainable variable and hence it will not be trained. It will stay constant throughout the training.

Comment: Yes I read this answer in another post but documentation doesn't describe it as with tf.Variable weights can be updated.. Can you please explain it a bit more. documentation says " it maintains state of the graph" What does it mean?